# Can a user edit the code in a Meteor template helper?

Tags: meteor

I am wanting to display parts of a page depending on the permissions of the logged in user. My template would look something like:

```
{{#if hasPermissions permission="SectionA"}}
Section A code...
{{/if}}

{{#if hasPermissions permission="SectionB"}}
Section B code...
{{/if}}
```

My template helper would contain a method called `hasPermission` which takes as a parameter `permission`. The result of the method would be a boolean true/false as to whether the user has permissions.

What I need to know is whether an end user would be able to either edit the `hasPermissions` code when it is client side or put a break point on and change the result before it is sent back? It is extremely important that users are not able to hack the client side code to allow them to see content they are not allowed to see.

If it is the case that users can edit the code - what is the way to achieve displaying sections of a page based on permissions?

Comment: "It is extremely important that users are not able to hack the client side code" - not going to happen. A user can do _anything_ with what you send him. He could even not be connecting from a web browser but only using DDP connections from another software and checking the results. Manage your security on the server-side with subscriptions and methods, not on the client-side.

Comment: @Kyll is correct. Anything goes on the client side. If a user gets past your permissions, there should still be checks on the server side to ensure that they can't execute or change anything outside of their defined role or permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **ALWAYS** check permissions on the **server side** to push only the permitted data to the client.

Then whether or not the client code is hacked, your template may display the 'empty shell' of that a permitted user would see, but s/he would not see any of the data.

In single page Apps like in Meteor, there is not much of a choice; someone may be able to display the template hacking around, but as long as the template itself is useless without the data, hacking the client code will just be a waste of time.